# ¿Cómo puedo borrar el último punto dibujado en una gráfica?

Tags: python

Me gustaría tener la opción de borrar el último punto que se ha dibujado asociando esa función con un botón.
Esta es una parte del código con el que dibujo los puntos al pulsar el botón 1, faltaría la función que borrara el último punto al pulsar el botón 2.
Gracias.

```
def registrar_coordenada(event):
x=[]
y=[]
if event.inaxes is not None:
    x.append(event.xdata)#me añade los puntos del grafico
    y.append(event.ydata)
q,w=x[0],y[0]
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.text(x.pop()+10,y.pop(), str(round(q) )+ ' : '+str(round (w,2)))
```

Comment: No tendría que ser `y.pop(-1)` ??

Comment: Como está me representa un punto en la gráfica cada vez que pulso el ratón. Lo que busco es como borrar el último punto que se ha representado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que, como dijo Christian, lo que buscas es el comando pop. Lo que debes hacer es

```
x.pop()
y.pop()
```

cuando se presione el segundo botón. Después de eso tendrías que limpiar la gráfica con

```
plt.clf
```

y volver a graficar.

Comment: Buenos días, gracias, ya soy capaz de borrar los puntos. ¿Sabéis si hay alguna forma de que mantenga el zoom que se le ha realizado a la gráfica? ya que al borrar los puntos, cada vez que ejecuto la función, al crear la gráfica de nuevo me quita el zoom. Gracias.

Comment: Me parece que no. Cuando vuelves a graficar volverá a su aspecto original.